# How is it possible to equating a variable to the variable itself?

Tags: javascript

I came over a JS somewhere in google documentation:

```
function doGet() {
  var feed =  UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://xkcd.com/rss.xml').getContentText();
  feed = feed.replace(
    /(&lt;img.*?alt="(.*?)".*?&gt;)/g,
    '$1' + new Array(10).join('&lt;br /&gt;') + '$2');
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(feed)
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);
}
```

First line declares the function. Second line declares the variable "feed". BUT thrid line is equating the "feed" with something "happening with feed".

How is it possible? It's something like declaring, 2 = 2 + 1.

Note: I just know the basics of JS.

Comment: that's an assignment, not comparison

Comment: `feed` is a variable. It's OK for the *current* value of the variable to appear on the right-hand side; it means that the statement should *update* the value of the variable, as in `x = x + 1;`.

Comment: It is not the same as `2 = 2 + 1`. 2 is an integer. `feed` is a variable. difference? variables can change. You set `feed` to `feed.replace` which feed is still feed until the replace is executed. I don't understand how you correlate 2 = 2 + 1, to this. No offense, but clearly you don't understand the basics of JS or any programming.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm actually that is one of the major complaints mathematicians (and functional programmers) have about "traditional" languages - they look (somewhat) similar to mathematical equations but don't behave anything like them. That's why code like that is not allowed in functional programming languages.

Comment: Well, that makes just as much sense as programmers giving math syntax critique. This isn't math, it's programming. And while they are loosely related, they are most definitely not the same thing. I think this is why some of my highly highly skilled math friends can't seem to grasp basic programming concepts.

Comment: FWIW, here is what happens according to the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation . Note how `GetValue` is only called for the right hand side, not the left hand side. In other words, while `feed` is referenced on the lhs and the rhs, only for the rhs we actually retrieve the value of `feed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first line you assign the text that is returned from a call to an API to the variable called `feed`.

At the second line you assign at the same variable, `feed` the result of applying a replace in the result you have taken above.

It's just this, nothing more or less.

By the way the operator `=` is the assignment operator. It is not related with the equality operator.

For further info about the latter, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable to a manipulated value of the variable. A simpler example than what you posted would be like this:

```
var myNumber = 20;

myNumber = myNumber + 20; //returns 40
```